# Field with display:none in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, display

In development environment my form is working correctly. But in production I find a city field (collection select) with a CSS attribute display: none;, which results in the collection select tag to not appear in my form.

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :city %>
 <%= f.collection_select :city_id, current_user.country.cities, :id, :name, {prompt: "المدينة" } %>
</div>
```

Comment: is this some kind of asset pipeline issue?

Comment: i don t know when o remove the div with class="field" the entire form not appear

Comment: add css `display:none !important`

Comment: but i don t want to hide it.